# Why does not nil query return values that are nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok this is mystifying me... I have the following query:

`Loan.where.not(billing_account_id: nil)`

However if I loop over the results it's returning some where the value is nil. What on earth is going on?

Comment: are the values actually 'nil'? or is it blank?

Comment: What does `Loan.where.not(billing_account_id: nil).pluck(:billing_account_id)` return?

Comment: It was part of a migration and the field doesn't exist anymore :(

Comment: The column billing_account_id is gone?  And the query isn't failing?  Did someone actually make a method called billing_account_id in your model lol.